# Change default OS from SageMaker Notebook Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

When creating a Notebook instance, I don't understand how to change the default OS image.
For example, I would have:

```
sh-4.2$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/ec2-user
```

But on SageMaker Studio, the default image is different when creating an instance:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

How can I use ubuntu image on SageMaker Notebook instance instead of "Amazon Linux AMI"?

Thanks

Related: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-al2.html

Comment: You should create a custom image built on amazon Linux. SM Studio runs docker images, every image has a base image (ubuntu, amzn linux,... ). To use amzn linux, create a custom image

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Studio's Jupyter server uses the same image as a SageMaker notebook instance, and they are not customizable as of today.

Studio notebooks use SageMaker images, which are container images that is compatible with SageMaker Studio, that are run as KernelGateway apps. You can [create your studio image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-byoi.html) if you need different functionalities.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.